# Polynomial irreducibility and perfect square.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Hi guys I am trying to show the following statement and would appreciate if people can take a look and comment if I am on the right track.

> $g(x,y)=y^2-p(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $p(x)$ is not a perfect square.

We are working over complex numbers.

Pf:
We will take the contra-positive. Thus we assume $p(x)$ is a perfect square and want to show that $g(x,y)$ is reducible. 
Clearly we can do $y^2-p(x)=0$ thus $y= \sqrt{p(x)}$ note that $\sqrt{p(x)}$ is a polynomial because p us a perfect square of another polynomial. Thus $g(x,y)=(y+\sqrt{p(x)})(y-\sqrt{p(x)})$.

I am struggling showing that if $g(x,y)$ is reducible then p(x) has to be a perfect square.My attempt so far is
let $g$ be reducible this $g(x,y)= k(x,y)m(x,y)$ without lost of generality assme that $m(x,y)= (ax+by)$.

Thus $k(x,y)(ax+by)=g(x,y)=y^2+p(x)$. Now I think I should make a divisibility argument that if you have $(ax+by)$ divide $y^2+p(x)$ we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ has degree $2$ in $y$, if $g$ is reducible then its factors must have degree $1$ in $y$:
$$
y^2-p(x) = (A(x)y+a(x))(B(x)y+b(x))=A(x)B(x)y^2+(A(x)b(x)+B(x)a(x))y+a(x)b(x)
$$
Therefore, $AB=1$, $Ab+Ba=0$, $ab=-p$.

Now $0=A(Ab+Ba)=A^2b+ABa$ and so $a=-A^2b$, which gives $-p=ab=-A^2b^2$ and so $p=(Ab)^2$.

Comment: Do we also have to discuss the possibility where one factor has degree $2$ in y and another factor does not have $y$? Like, $$y^{2}-p(x)=(A(x)y^{2}+B(x)y+C(x))\cdot D(x),$$ which leads to $D(x)A(x)=1$ and $D(x)C(x)=-p(x)$, but then I do not know how to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical, yes, I think we need to handle this too. Good catch. But then $AD=1$ implies $D$ is a nonzero constant, and so a unit.

Comment: Brilliant! By the way, does $AD=1$ imply that both $A$ and $D$ are nonzero constant and is reciprocal of each other? (Like, there is no way for two non-constant polynomial multiplying each other to get $1$, right?) So, in the proof you posted here, $AB=1$ also implies that $A,B$ are nonzero constant, right? Just curious, it does not change the proof. Thank you so much!